# identifier "string" undefined?

Tags: c++, string

I am receiving the error: identifier "string" undefined.

However, I am including string.h and in my main file, everything is working fine.

CODE:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

class difficulty
{
private:
    int lives;
    string level;
public:
    difficulty(void);
    ~difficulty(void);

    void setLives(int newLives);
    int getLives();

    void setLevel(string newLevel);
    string getLevel();
};
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is occurring?

Comment: As a side comment, you should use include guards in your code. If your compiler does better with the `#pragma once` directive, combine the two: `#ifndef XXX_HEADER // #define XXX_HEADER // #pragma once // ... // #endif` where the order is important (i.e. include guard enclosing the pragma)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`<string.h>` is the old C header. C++ provides `<string>`, and then it should be referred to as `std::string`.

Comment: Don't `using namespace std`, I've already downvoted all the answers that recommend that for a reason.

Answer (score 27):

You want to do `#include <string>` instead of `string.h` and then the type `string` lives in the `std` namespace, so you will need to use `std::string` to refer to it.

Answer (score 14):

You forgot the namespace you're referring to. Add

`using namespace std;`

to avoid std::string all the time.

Comment: For those who downvoted: thanks for your constructive comments :P

Comment: `using namespace std;` is really bad, especially in a header.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why?

Comment: There's an SO question about it, I believe.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) (if someone wants to know)

Answer (score 11):

Because `string` is defined in the namespace `std`. Replace `string` with `std::string`, or add

```
using std::string;
```

below your `include` lines.

It probably works in `main.cpp` because some other header has this `using` line in it (or something similar).

Answer (score 6):

`#include <string>` would be the correct c++ include, also you need to specify the namespace with `std::string` or more generally with `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you wanted to `#include<string>`, not `<string.h>`. `std::string` also needs a namespace qualification, or an explicit `using` directive.

Answer (score 5):

You must use std namespace. If this code in main.cpp you should write

```
using namespace std;
```

If this declaration is in header, then you shouldn't include namespace and just write

```
std::string level;
```