# Identifier [string value] is undefined

Tags: c++, string, undefined

I have been making a project on C++ and I am having trouble assigning a value to a string name. I made sure to include the string library (and I did try string.h), but when I attempted to assign a value to the string name with the data type "string", it gave me the message "Error: identifier (value I assigned the string) is undefined". This is kind of what the code looked like:

```
string a = start;
```

The word "start" was underlined in red. It was weird because when I did the same thing using an integer, it worked just fine:

```
int a = 3;
```

Can somebody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your value into quotes:

```
string a = "Hello World!";
```

But, you also need to include the right headers:

```
#include <string> //string.h is for c-strings
using namespace std; //so you don't have to do std::xxxxxx
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, and I did originally include the string library and use namespace std.

Answer (score 1):

See [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146719/identifier-string-undefined?rq=1).  You should first include the header `<string>` (not `<string.h>`), and then write your statement as `std::string a = start`.  Here, `std::string` indicates that `string` is located in the namespace `std`.